# creating a mount helper

Tags: filesystems, mount

I want to create a mount helper to be able to mount a filesystem not currently supported by mount.

I'm not sure about what the helper should put in the mount folder, what happen after the mount when I try to navigate the folder (with ls for example), will it call the helper again ?

I'm having trouble finding documentation on the subject.

Comment: What do you mean by “not currently supported by mount”? Is this some custom FUSE filesystem? Does [systemd.automount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) come close to what you need?

Comment: This is a remote filesystem that is accessed through asynchonous call. Nothing could work apart from a home made tool

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: Thank you, FUSE seems to be exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're calling a “mount helper” is, given what you want to do with it, a [drier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) for a filesystem type. Calling a filesystem driver a “mount helper” is misleading because it makes it look like it's a piece of software that's only used while mounting. The filesystem driver is a piece of software that's used as long as the filesystem is mounted.

There's no such thing as a “mount folder”. Each time you access a filesystem, the request is dispatched to the corresponding driver which performs the request in the way that depends on the filesystem type. For example, for filesystem types that are stored on a disk, the filesystem driver access sectors of the disk. For filesystem types that are accessed over the network, the filesystem driver communicates over the network, and so on. See [How does Linux, the kernel, mount filesystems? What actually does this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86787/how-does-linux-the-kernel-mount-filesystems-what-actually-does-this/86814#86814) for a slightly more detailed explanation.

The kernel can handle a number of filesystems. If you're looking for support for a more exotic filesystem, check if there exists a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) driver for it. FUSE allows filesystem drivers to be implemented by an unprivileged program rather than by kernel code. The [FUSE project wiki](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Filesystems) and [the old page on Sourceforge](http://web.archive.org/web/20151115105538/http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/FileSystems) list some existing FUSE filesystems. A web search may reveal more.